# Python Create Count of Letters from Text File

Tags: python

I'm trying to do a count of the letters only from a text file. I want to exclude any punctuation and spaces. Here's what I have so far. I've been searching for ways to do this, but I keep getting errors whenever I try to exclude certain characters. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
#Read Text Files To Memory
with open("encryptedA.txt") as A:
    AText = A.read()
with open("encryptedB.txt") as B:
    BText = B.read()

#Create Dictionary Object
from collections import Counter
CountA = Counter(AText)
print(CountA)
CountB = Counter(BText)
print(CountB)
```

Comment: Maybe you want `Counter(c for c in AText if c.isalnum())`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are on the right track, but you want to filter the text-file based on characters that are alphabetic (using `isalpha()`) or alphanumeric (using `isalnum()`):

```
from collections import Counter
with open('data.txt') as f:
    print (Counter(c for c in f.read() if c.isalpha())) # or c.isalnum()
```

For my sample file, this prints:

```
Counter({'t': 3, 'o': 3, 'r': 3, 'y': 2, 's': 2, 'h': 2, 'p': 2, 'a': 2, 'g': 1, 'G': 1, 'H': 1, 'i': 1, 'e': 1, 'M': 1, 'S': 1})
```

Comment: @dawg That doesn't work, at least in Python 3. You would need to do `c for line in f for c in line`